# MVC Model Binding for EditorFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-binding, editorfor

I have three class types `Search`, `BaseSearch` and `TextSearch` of the following relation. `Search` is composed of a `List<BaseSearch>` and `TextSearch` inherits from `BaseSearch`, `BaseSearch` is abstract.

Now I would like to use Html helper to draw a list of `TextSearch`, EditorTemplate is below

```
@model GenericSearch.Models.TextSearch


<table class="form-group container">
    <tr class="row">
        <td class=" col-sm-2 " style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;height: 50px; ">
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Label, Model.Label, new { @class = "control-label pull-right" })
        </td>
        <td class=" col-sm-2 " style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;height: 50px; ">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Comparators, new SelectList(Model.Comparators, "Value", "Text"), new { @class = "form-control", style = "width:150px" })
        </td>
        <td class="col-sm-8 form-inline" style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;height: 50px;">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Value, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I have a razor view for Index as below

```
@model GenericSearch.Models.Search

<div class="row">

    @using (@Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        {
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.List)
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Apply filters</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    }


</div>
```

And two Index action at the controller as below

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {            
        Search search = new Models.Search();
        search.List= new List<BaseSearch>();

        TextSearch text = new TextSearch();
        text.Label = "Text1";

        search.MyProperty.Add(text);

        return View(search);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(Search search)
    {
        return View(search);
    }
```

This setting is rendered fine, however when I fill the rendered text boxes and post it through the submit button, I am expecting to receive the `Search` class populated with the `List<TextSearch>` that has properties filled with the values entered by the user at the HttpPost Index. But I get an error saying that this can't be done because `BaseClass` is abstract, when I remove the abstract keyword from the `BaseClass` the `Search` class gets instantiated but with a `List<BaseSearch>` instead of a `List<TextSearch>` also it has its properties empty, not filled with the data user entered. What am I missing here?

EDIT

```
public class Search
{

    public List<BaseSearch> List { get; set; }
}

    public abstract class BaseSearch
{
    string label;
    protected List<Comparator> comparators;

    public string Label
    {
        get
        {
            return label;
        }
        set
        {
            label = value;
        }
    }

    public List<Comparator> Comparators
    {
        get
        {
            return comparators;
        }
        set
        {
            comparators = value;
        }
    }

    public BaseSearch()
    {
        comparators = new List<Models.Comparator>();
    }

}

public class TextSearch : BaseSearch
{
    string _value;

    public string Value
    {
        get
        {
            return _value;
        }
        set
        {
            _value = value;
        }
    }

    public TextSearch() : base()
    {
        comparators.Add(new Comparator() { Value = -1, Text = Resources.Choose });
        comparators.Add(new Comparator() { Value = 1, Text = Resources.StartWith });
        comparators.Add(new Comparator() { Value = 2, Text = Resources.Contains });
    }
}
```

Comment: For a start you cannot bind a `<select>` to a list of complex objects (which is what `Comparators` must be (e.g. `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`) - a `<select>` binds to and posts back a single value. You need to show you models.

Comment: I have added the model above, please check. Nevermind about the <Select> let's talk about the simple value Value at the TextSearch class, why it is not binding? also why the Search class returned at the Index has List<BaseSearch> instead of List<TextSearch>.

Comment: You have not shown your model for `Search`. And your code in the `Index()` method does not even compile (what is `integer` in  `search.MyProperty.Add(integer);` And what is `List` in `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.List)`). The only thing I can interpret from what you have shown is you have a property named `MyProperty` which is type of `List<BaseSearch>()`. What is you property that is `List<TextSearch>`?

Comment: I have added the Search class, the integer was corrected to text and the MyProperty was corrected to List, I am very sorry for the confusion, thanks for your efforts.

Comment: But `Search` only contains a property which is `List<BaseSearch>`. The process of model binding involves the `DefaultModelBinder` initializing your model and reading the values in the request to set its properties. It initializes `search` which contains a property which is `List<BaseSearch>` so if it finds matching names in the request it adds instances of `BaseSearch` (it cant possibly know that you actually want `TextSearch`, or any other class which implements `BaseSearch`)

Comment: I am very sorry, I am pretty new to MVC so I am not really getting your point, could you please post the modified code as an answer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157131/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-sisyphus).